# How can I print in a if function some numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to print the numbers from an input, but only the numbers given by the user. I don't know how can I do this. The excersice I'm trying to do it's basicalle about grades and if some grades are equal or grater than 7, I have to print all those numbers that the user gives greater or equal than 7. This is what I write so far:

```
while another == "Yes" :
    grades = int(input("Add the grade of the student: "))
    another = input("Do you want to add another grade? Yes/No: ")
```

Comment: You can save them to a list to filter'em when the `while` is done

Answer (score 0):

This example prints the good grades as they are entered

```
another = "Yes"
while another == "Yes" :
    grades = int(input("Add the grade of the student: "))
    if (grades >= 7):
        print(grades)
    another = input("Do you want to add another grade? Yes/No: ")
```

This example prints the good grades after the user is done entering them.

```
another = "Yes"
list_of_grades = []
while another == "Yes":
    grades = int(input("Add the grade of the student: "))
    if (grades >= 7):
        list_of_grades.append(grades)
    another = input("Do you want to add another grade? Yes/No: ")

for item in list_of_grades:
    print(item)
```